# python error: 'Undefined name'. But the same code works elsewhere. How to remove the need to import variables in every .py file?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, python-import

My question comes from an error but I have solved it. The problem is I have seen it working elsewhere without my solution and I don't know why. I'm sure one of you python gurus can explain it.

How can I make the interpreter see through the layers of import without importing and declaring in every layer?

The reason for my question is where I took this code from (InstaPy by timgrossmann on GitHub) it works without the repeat import and reference. It seems there's a whole section of python I need to learn and I don't even know what it's called.

Here's my code and the solution to the error follows at the end:

myScript.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from xpath import read_path

#the following doesn't work because myScript can't see the items imported to xpath.py
username_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            read_xpath(login_user.__name__, "username"))
```

xpath.py

```
from xpath_compile import xpath


def read_xpath(function_name, xpath_name):
    return xpath[function_name][xpath_name]
```

xpath_compile.py

```
xpath = {}

xpath["login_user"] = {
    "input_password": "//input[@name='password']",
    "input_username": "//input[@name='username']",
}
```

Here's my solution (added import of xpath and referenced it before the variable tag):

```
from xpath import read_path
from xpat_compile import xpath

username_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            read_xpath(xpath.login_user.__name__, "username"))
```

Comment: please double check you code snippets for typos. you have `read_path` and `read_xpath`, `login_user` and `xpath.login_user`, `xpath_compile` and `xpat_compile`. also post the complete error message. also post the full link to the code on github.

Answer (score 1):

**Initially you have:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from xpath import read_path

#the following doesn't work because myScript can't see the items imported to xpath.py
username_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            read_xpath(login_user.__name__, "username"))
```

and it would nice to introduce here Python Namespaces.
In total there is 4 range-types of namespaces: Local, Enclosing, Global, Builtin resulting so-called LEGB rule when it comes to priority of them.

**But what is Namespace?**

By my words, it is collection of names being available for different scope of program. It is implemented by dictionaries, apart of builtin Namespace (works as module).

```
from xpath import read_path
```

Then in your script (myScript.py) by the above import was added to Global Namespace only name: read_path (nothing more). You can check all availble names (variable, classes, functions) in your Global Namespace by using builtin function dir(). However initially you tried to use the 'login_user' name which was definitelly not included to your Global Namespace.

I am recomending you to read simply about **Python modules:**
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thank you for sharing that information. As I don't want to package my 
code I have gone ahead and updated my code to use only sting inputs as follows:
`read_xpath("string1", "string2")` the method used in InstaPy is still a bit of a mystery to me.